# react native socket io does not work on production mode

Tags: react-native, socket.io, network-programming, expo, chat

i have a react native app that i'm trying to have a chat functionality with , which worked just great and just as i expected until i was ready to post for production . the whole code works perfectly with expo start and development mode but when i run the app with production mode sockets do not work at all. or they work partially.

i have two apps and in one it recieves but don't send messages and the other one doesn't do anything at all(one is android and the other is ios).

i'm connecting to my socket io using the following:

in App.js...

```
import { SocketContext , socket } from "./context/socket";

    return (
  <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
      <StatusBar />
      <Toast ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  </SocketContext.Provider>
);
```

in my socket.js file i have:

```
import  OpenSocket  from "socket.io-client";
import { API_URL } from "../constants/API";
import React from 'react';
import useRoom from "../tools/useRoom";
import useSession from "../tools/useSession" ; 
import useUser from "../tools/useUser" ;
// import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
// import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

 export const  userIDStorage = 'user-id'

//  const {userID , sessionID } = await getUserID();

export const socket = OpenSocket.connect(API_URL); 






socket.on('connect',()=>{
console.log('user connected...');
// TODO ==> check if there is a local room saved and if it is active...



});




export const SocketContext =  React.createContext();
```

and in my chat page i have the following to call and emit from the socket ::

```
import { SocketContext } from "../../context/socket";


  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
```

in the rest of the page i just call

```
socket.emit('something',{data});
```

as such...

anyways there is no output to actually get in expo production mode apps but i was able to deduce that when the app is in production mode sockets aren't firing by testing every line of the code alone on different events... and when i'm in development mode everything works as it should.

Note :

for the server side i'm using a heroku hosted express but i didn't add anything about it here cuz i tested the apps on development mode with the production server and they work fine it's just when they are in producion mode they don't work anymore.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm currently facing the same issue

Comment: i'm not working on that project anymore , But what i found at the time is that Expo didn't support sockets yet. I did contact them but don't know if they've fixed it or not.


i also tries working with webSocket directly without relying on socket.io but it also doesn't work (it may work with one way connections but not for chat systems).

anyways it used to be an expo specific problem. 

i'm sorry if this wasn't helpful.